# Is it possible to call webRequest when application goes in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I want to upload images when home button pressed and application goes in background.
Is it possible? If yes then how? and if no then do i have any other alternative?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a task in background by using this code for a specific time-

```
 UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
    }];
    self.silenceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(startLocationServices) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Refer this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

I think this will help u. :)

Comment: Thank you.... i concluded by reading apple document that the uploading process can be executed for maximum 10 mins after application goes to the background,

Answer (score 1):

An app can request to run in the background for up to 10 minutes after it has been closed so that it can finish a long-running task. Only some processes are allowed to run in background. See **Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks** section [in this reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28)

If your app is allowed so, you can try below code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you

        // stopped or ending the task outright.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }];



    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.



        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    });

}
```

if you want to know how much time your app has left to run

```
NSTimeInterval ti = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]backgroundTimeRemaining];
NSLog(@"Remaining Time: %f", ti); // just for debug
```

For more ref go with this [reference PDF(page 60)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf)